# Importing a scala class packaged with sbt in java maven project

Tags: java, scala, maven, sbt

I have built a library written in scala with sbt and published it to my local maven repository using `sbt publishM2`. The jar file is now within a subdirectory of my `.m2` directory and I can see all classes just fine using `jar -tf`. Subsequently I created a java maven project from which I would like to use my scala library. Maven can find the jar file, but I cannot import classes from the jar file. Just as if all classes within the scala library were private. Yet in scala there is no modifier `public` for classes. The docs say that public is the default assumed when no modifier is given. What am I missing?

**EDIT:**
I had a problem with my maven groupId (this is the organization in sbt). While sbt seems to allow slashes as organizations, groupIds do not seem to allow them. I replaced the slash with a dot in the groupId, leaving the organization as is. Now everything works fine.

Comment: Try to be more specific. What errors do you get when you try to import those classes?